# NuxtJS how to pass script data to globally usage?

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt JS beginner to VueJs

Nuxt JS I am trying to have data access globally but I am not sure how to do it?

I did create a script in layouts>default.vue

but it seems like it is not working

I really do not want to paste the script data into all pages over again and again

Or is it my script something wrong with data structure?

```
layouts>default.vue 
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app class="one">
      <vueTop />
      <v-content>
        <!-- Main Content here -->
        <nuxt />
      </v-content>
      <vueBottom />
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vueTop from "~/components/vueTop.vue";
import vueBottom from "~/components/vueBottom.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    vueTop,
    vueBottom
  },
data() {
    return {
      posts: {
        "0000000001": {
          id: "0000000001",
          title: "testing1",
          description: "this is testing1",
          url: "/cat2/testing1",
          category: "1000000002"
        },
        "0000000002": {
          id: "0000000002",
          title: "testing2",
          description: "this is testing2",
          url: "/cat2/testing2",
          category: "1000000002"
        },
        "00000000003": {
          id: "0000000003",
          title: "testing3",
          description: "this is testing3",
          url: "/cat3/testing3",
          category: "1000000003"
        },
        "0000000004": {
          id: "0000000004",
          title: "testing4",
          description: "this is testing4",
          url: "/cat3/testing4",
          category: "1000000003"
        },
        "0000000005": {
          id: "0000000005",
          title: "testing5",
          description: "this is testing5",
          url: "/cat1/testing5",
          category: "1000000001"
        },
        "0000000006": {
          id: "0000000006",
          title: "testing6",
          description: "this is testing6",
          url: "/cat1/testing6",
          category: "1000000001"
        }
      },
      categories: {
        "1000000001": {
          text: "cat1"
        },
        "1000000002": {
          text: "cat2"
        },
        "1000000003": {
          text: "cat3"
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using constants

**constants.js**

```
export const categories = {
        "1000000001": {
          text: "cat1"
        },
        "1000000002": {
          text: "cat2"
        },
        "1000000003": {
          text: "cat3"
        }
      }
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
<script>
import { categories } from 'constants.js';

export default {

}
</script>
```